# do I need a server for a live chat system on my app

Tags: android, ios, google-app-engine, server

I need to make a live chat for my app. Do I absolutely 100% need a server or is there another way to do it. I'm on a low budget thanks!

Comment: This question lacks any sign of effort or research on the op's side. It is also too broad to give a good and specific answer that would be in any way useful as a stackoverflow topic. I have therefor flagged this post as **too broad**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you need a server to develop a live chat system. Even if you use Apple's default APNS (Apple Push Notification Service) or Google's GCM (Google cloud messaging), you have to use your own server to send message or notification. 
You have to learn or hire someone to develop server side application. Nodejs can be used to develop the chat system fast. You may try https://www.heroku.com/ for testing purpose as it's free to some extent.

Answer (score 0):

You can try some free backend server.

EX:

- https://www.firebase.com/
- https://quickblox.com/